# Squid расположение keytab

Tags: squid

Centos7, Squid 3.5.

Squid не может найти keytab файл, который лежит в каталоге /etc/squid/proxy.keytab.
В cache.log такой текст:

```html
negotiate_kerberos_auth.cc(487): pid=10259 :2018/07/10 16:48:02| negotiate_kerberos_auth: INFO: Starting version 3.0.4sq
2018/07/10 16:48:02 kid1| Starting new negotiateauthenticator helpers...
2018/07/10 16:48:02 kid1| helperOpenServers: Starting 1/10 'negotiate_kerberos_auth' processes
negotiate_kerberos_auth.cc(546): pid=10258 :2018/07/10 16:48:02| negotiate_kerberos_auth: INFO: Setting keytab to FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab
negotiate_kerberos_auth.cc(75): pid=10258 :2018/07/10 16:48:02| negotiate_kerberos_auth: ERROR: krb5_kt_start_seq_get failed: Key table file '/etc/krb5.keytab' not found
2018/07/10 16:48:02| negotiate_kerberos_auth: ERROR: krb5_kt_start_seq_get: Key table file '/etc/krb5.keytab' not found
negotiate_kerberos_auth.cc(75): pid=10258 :2018/07/10 16:48:02| negotiate_kerberos_auth: ERROR: krb5_read_keytab failed: Key table file '/etc/krb5.keytab' not found
2018/07/10 16:48:02| negotiate_kerberos_auth: ERROR: krb5_read_keytab: Key table file '/etc/krb5.keytab' not found
negotiate_kerberos_auth.cc(556): pid=10258 :2018/07/10 16:48:02| negotiate_kerberos_auth: ERROR: Reading keytab FILE:/etc/krb5.keytab into list failed
```

Т .е. как указать Squid'у, что это файл искать там?
Можно конечно положить файл в /etc, как krb5.keytab, но всё таки?
Спасибо.

Comment: Извиняюсь, но указанной части лога упоминания о proxy.keytab не вижу

Comment: Ну да, Squid ищет его в /etc/krb5.keytab

Comment: Надо ещё раз пересмотреть примерные файлы настроек: что говорится в них?

Comment: Justicet, разобрался, нужно было поправить krb5.conf.

Comment: Ну и отлично! Как всегда внимательнее к примерам в .confах и все будет в порядке ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для подобных настроек у сквида есть специальный файл: `/etc/sysconfig/squid`.

В который надо добавить следующее:

```
KRB5RCACHETYPE=none
export KRB5RCACHETYPE

KRB5_KTNAME=/etc/squid/proxy.keytab
export KRB5_KTNAME
```

Править "общесистемный" файл `krb5.conf` под один сервис не очень хорошо. Что, если на этом сервере придется поднимать еще один kerberos-сервис, который прочитает сквидовый keytab?

Comment: > Что, если на этом сервере придется поднимать еще один kerberos-сервис, который прочитает сквидовый keytab?
Тоже подумал об этом. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Нужно в krb5.conf внести запись default_keytab_name = /etc/squid/proxy.keytab
Тогда будет искать файл там.